# Metro Xaml binding to DataContext.Object.Property not working

Tags: xaml

I am setting the datacontext of my xaml page to a viewmodel passed in to the construrctor.  My viewmodel has an object called Item, which has a property called Category.

```
public DataEntry(DEViewModel vm)
{
InitializeComponent();
this.vm = vm;
this.DataContext = this.vm;
}
```

I am trying to bind to the ViewModel.Item.Category property like so:

```
<TextBox Name="txtCategory" Text="{Binding Path=Item.Category, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This does not work.  If I set the datacontext to vm.Item, and bind to Category it works.

Any ideas on how to bind to a property that is hanging off of an object on the viewmodel?

---

Thanks, Terrence

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
<TextBox Name="txtCategory" 
    Text="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    DataContext="{Binding Item}" />
```

The reason it was not working is because it will only look at property notifications for the `DataContext`, so just set the local `DataContext` for the control to `Item` and the control will handle property notifications for `Item`.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your input, but that solution did not work, can you try it on your end?

Comment: Did it pop up with an error message of some kind? Or did it just not bind to the field?

Comment: It just didn't bind the value to the text box. If i set the datacontext on the page to object.item, and text {binding category} it works.

Comment: Well I am using this solution in a few places in my own project. All I can say is that the DataContext of the text box should be bound to "object.item" then the fields that are local to "object.item" should be accessible and two way bindable on the individual textbox control.